# Two Regexp in a loop ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic, pattern-matching

```
Function VeriBul(BaslangicDegeri,BitisDegeri)

  Set RegEx = New RegExp
  RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
  RegEx.Global = True
  RegEx.Pattern = "(" & BaslangicDegeri & ")(.+?)(" & BitisDegeri & ")"
  Set Sonuc = RegEx.Execute(Mid(strRetval,29600,254000))

  For Each i in Sonuc
 VeriBul =  VeriBul & tr2(i.SubMatches(1))

    Set RegEx2 = New RegExp
    RegEx2.IgnoreCase = True
    RegEx2.Global = True
    RegEx2.Pattern = "(<hemenalfiyat>)(.+?)(</hemenalfiyat>)"
    Set Sonucx = RegEx2.Execute(Mid(strRetval,33000,2000))

     For Each y in Sonucx
     VeriBul2 =  VeriBul2 & tr2(y.SubMatches(1))
     Next

     When it works then appering error

  Next
```

======================================================

```
For Each i in Sonuc
  i.SubMatches(1)

For Each y in Sonucx
  y.SubMatches(1)

  Next
  Next
```

How I can print this except Submatches code? because I have two regexp code (so Im used as Regex2) like that and I can't use to Submatches again.

Thanks,

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Please include a sample of the input string and a sample of the desired output.  This may help clarify what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I shared all codes, thanks @AnthonyWJones

Comment: Whilst I'm sure that will be useful that wasn't what I asked you for.   Reading someone elses disfunctional code when the code's intent is still not understood is not very helpful.

Comment: I edited again, hope you understand that's time @AnthonyWJones

Comment: It's a bit clearer, but you could help a lot by showing some example input, some example output as you're getting it now, and some example output as you'd like to have it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to fix this without the rest of your code (tr2) and your input and desired output but i gues your code should be something like this

```
Function VeriBul(BaslangicDegeri,BitisDegeri)

  Set RegEx = New RegExp
  RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
  RegEx.Global = True
  RegEx.Pattern = "(" & BaslangicDegeri & ")(.+?)(" & BitisDegeri & ")"

  Set RegEx2 = New RegExp
  RegEx2.IgnoreCase = True
  RegEx2.Global = True
  RegEx2.Pattern = "(<hemenalfiyat>)(.+?)(</hemenalfiyat>)"

  Set Sonuc = RegEx.Execute(Mid(strRetval,29600,254000))
  Set Sonucx = RegEx2.Execute(Mid(strRetval,33000,2000))

  For Each i in Sonuc
    VeriBul =  VeriBul & tr2(i.SubMatches(1))
  Next
  For Each y in Sonucx
   VeriBul =  VeriBul & tr2(y.SubMatches(1))
  Next

Next
```

Comment: thanks so much, but It must return i.SubMatches(1) times that why I'm trying to use nested. Could u check to codes again? I added to something that I want under to post.


For Each i in Sonuc
  i.SubMatches(1)

For Each y in Sonucx
  y.SubMatches(1)

  Next
  Next

Comment: sorry, can't follow you, publish some input and desired output

Comment: I just want use create 2 loop via different veriables.

**
 For Each i in Sonuc
    VeriBul =  VeriBul & tr2(i.SubMatches(1))
  Next

  For Each y in Sonucx
   VeriBul =  VeriBul & tr2(y.SubMatches(1))
  Next
**
How I can do this just with ONE FOR EACH LOOP?